# Aligning the elements using bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created bootstrap menu items and kept `FLIP` option beside that.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/HMJ9a/)

Here issue is that `FLIP` should be just beside the box, but it is appearing downside?

HTML:

```
<div class="magic-container">               
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="typeahead form-control" placeholder="Select category ..." />
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li id="one"><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                    <li id="two"><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                    <li id="three"><a href="#">Politics</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                    <li id="four"><a href="#">Business</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                    <li id="four"><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                    <li id="four"><a href="#">Celebrity</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>

                <span class="flip">
                    <span class="dropDownFlip">    
                        <a href="#"> FLIP </a> 
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `input` is having a width of 100% being applied to it. It is being applied from the `bootstrap.min.css` file. By adding the following to your css it fixes your issue:

```
.input-group .form-control {
    width: auto;
}
```

Here is your [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bkjDc/) updated.

**Update:** Since this is a change to an existing class and could possibly affect elements elsewhere on your page/site, you could create a new class for this particular instance. Something like this would work:

```
.input-group .floatLeft {
    float: left !important;
    width: auto;
}
```

and just add the class `floatLeft` to your input.

Comment: Thanks dude, But this can make affect on positioning of other elements

Comment: @cyclic see my update. Instead of making the change in the `bootstrap.min.css` file, just create a new class and apply it to your input. Same concept, but won't change positioning of other elements using the `form-control` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following styles in you stylesheets

```
.magic-container .input-group input {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%;
    width: 70%;
    }

.flip {
    float: left;
    }
```